# Can we use multiple names in package.json file and do an npm intstall by specifying that name?

Tags: angularjs, package, npm-install

My main project is combined with different services(like frontend,backend,algolia,notification etc).

Each have a specific **package.json** file.I want to combine all the different package.json files into a single package.json file and replace all other with that file.

Is that possible?

> the dependencies in package.json files are different

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

If your project has multiple package.json files then you have multiple modules. Consider separating them and installing them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.further,now the package.json files are in seperate modules as you said.i want to combine them in a single package.json for readability purpose and keep each package.json(that contains dependencies from all modules) in separate modules as how it is now.can i use any custom name for combining all or is this not possible?

Comment: like we add devDependencies ,is there any way for specifying custom dependencies (here in a sense that dependencies of Module A,ModuleB etc.) and install that only along with npm install command?

Comment: @neerajnarayanan No, it's not possible. You can only have dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies. See the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json